# weak convergence and Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X$ be a real random variable and $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of real random variable, such that :
$$\exists \alpha>0; \lim_n\int_{\mathbb{R}}|F_{X_n}(x)-F_X(x)|^{\alpha}dx=0$$

I need to prove that $(X_n)_n$ converges weakly to $X$.

I am thankful for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: follow the following steps:

1) there is a subsequence $F_{X_{n_j}}$ converging almost everywhere to $F_X$. Since complement of a set of measure $0$ is dense it follows that $F_{X_{n_j}}(x)$ converges to $F_X(x)$ for all $x$ in dense set.

2) Use standard argument to show that 1) and monotonicity of $F_X$ implies converges at every point $x$ where $F_X$ is continuous.

3) Conclude that $X_{n_j}$ converges weakly to $X$.

4) Apply the above result to subsequences of $F_{X_n}$ to conclude that the entire sequence $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$.  [ Weak convergence is equivalent to the fact that $Ef(X_n) \to Ef(X)$ for every bounded continuous function. From this it follows that if every subsequence of $X_n$ has a further subsequence which  converges weakly to $X$ then $X_n \to X$ weakly].

Comment: you want to say that $(X_n)_n$ converges weakly to $X$ if and only if from any subsequence of $(X_n)_n$ there exists a further sub-subsequence which converges weakly to $X$

Comment: @mathex Yes, I have added some details to step 4).

Comment: 1) is simple since we have convergence in $L^{\alpha}$, but why if we have the convergence of $F_{X_n}$ on a dense set, this implies the convergence at every point of continuity of $F_X$

Comment: @mathex Use squeeze theorem: if $a<x<y$ where $a$ and $b$ are continuity points then $F_{X_{n_j}} (a) \leq F_{X_{n_j}} (x) \leq F_{X_{n_j}} (b)$ and $F_X(a) \leq F_X(x) \leq F_X(b)$. Using the fact that $F_{X_{n_j}} (a) \to F(X(a)$ and $F_{X_{n_j}} (b) \to F(X(b)$ and the fact that we can make $F_X(a)$ and $F_X(b)$ both close to $F_X(x)$ if $F_X$ is continuous at $x$ you can see that $F_{X_{n_j}} (x) \to F_X(x)$.